# All Time Rolling Average based on string order with multiple conditions in the same column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate the average $ amounts per category (X & Y) and their sub-categories (A,B,C,D,E) on a rolling basis based on past data that's on a string format. There are 2 types of calculations:

1. A rate applied to the future based on the previous results. (solved).
2. An average of all time prior to the current string in the column. (need assistance).

Struggling to set OR conditions in my AVERAGEIFS function to read from a particular string the previous strings and their data on a rolling basis. I tried doing it with AVERAGE and FILTER but kept getting an error, so tried again with AVERAGEIFS but no positive results yet.

This is the current state of my formula:

​=IF(OR(D$9="",$A10=""),"",IFERROR(
IF($B$3="Rate",C10*(1+$B$4), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="All Time",$B10=""),AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$B:$B,$A10,data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="All Time",$B10<>""),AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$C:$C,$B10,data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="Last 3",$B10=""), AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$B:$B,$A10, data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-1), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-2), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-3), data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="Last 3",$B10<>""), AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$C:$C,$B10, data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-1), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-2), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-3), data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="Last 6",$B10=""), AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$B:$B,$A10, data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-1), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-2), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-3), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-4), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-5), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-6), data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9), IF(AND($B$3="Average",$B$5="Last 6",$B10<>""), AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$C:$C,$B10, data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-1), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-2), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-3), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-4), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-5), data!$A:$A,INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(data!$A:$A,data!$A:$A<>"")))-6), data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9)))))))),"ERROR"))

Tables:

| Col1 | Category 1 | Category 2 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple-1 | X | A | $0.00 | $1,000.00 |
| Apple-1 | Y | C | $15.00 | $0.00 |

​It would be of great help if somebody could help me solve this complex problem. My ideas are to potentially add a sequential list of numbers assigned to each string, so that the AVERAGEIFS formula can figure out at which strings in the past to look for.

Please find below Edit access to the public GSheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LFiYfiaZ9PBwlhEHSVEMibgQzBGDfFCQhx96erUZYvg/edit?usp=sharing

Expected end result:

[image]

Comment: Please insert another table to show the _manually entered_ desired results you would like to get from the data you listed. Highlight clearly what makes this question different from your [previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172835/269219). The formula you quote is probably not going to be of use here, so you could remove it to make the question a bit briefer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula might not be correct due to the usage of AVERAGEIFS(data!$D:$D,data!$B:$B,$A10,data!$A:$A,"<="&D$9). Since data!$A:$A is text, you can't use '<=' directly. Could you replace the entire formula with one that returns an array of results?